# Can we redistribute OpenJDK tools.jar?

Tags: java

My application needs some classes of `tools.jar`.

Many sources converge to say that one cannot redistribute tools.jar from Oracle JDK without redistributing the whole bundle.

However, the case of OpenJDK's `tools.jar` is less clear. (the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305686/is-it-safe-to-distribute-tools-jar-along-with-a-java-application-bundle is quite ambiguous)

https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ may know better whether one can redistribute OpenJDK's `tools.jar` in a bundled application or on Maven central.

Answer (score 4):

The original OpenJDK (and NOT any pre-built Java download from java.net) is licensed primarily under the [GPL 2.0 with Classpath exception](http://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html). The [OPENJDK ASSEMBLY EXCEPTION](http://openjdk.java.net/legal/assembly-exception.html) also applies to some parts of the code. The net effect of this licensing is that the GPL applies to the `tools.jar` but does not extend to code that would link and use `tools.jar`

Therefore if I bundle the OpenJDK `tools.jar` (assumed to be un-modified) in some of my software I would:

1. comply with the GPL 2.0 attribution requirements for `tools.jar`, adding the  exceptions texts.
2. redistribute per the GPL the corresponding source code of the classes and binaries included in `tools.jar`.

These are rather simple requirements: yet you should refer to the GPL for the exact details of what these two items mean.

I am no longer a Java expert but I think that the source code should be available [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/).

Because Oracle does not make available pre-built binaries for the OpenJDK `tools.jar`  but instead only provide JDK binaries using another license than the GPL (a limited proprietary license called the `Oracle BCL`), I would not use any pre-built binaries provided by Oracle. Instead I would compile from source the `tools.jar` myself. Or, if this is available as a pre-built Jar in Maven central, before using this I would verify that this was indeed built from sources and that the exact corresponding source code is available me to redistribute alongside with my software.