# Can I use JavaFX in a Commercial Application for Free?

Tags: commercial, java, non-commercial

There is so much confusion regarding this simple question it's driving me crazy. The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16886580/4594511) says

> there is no difference between JavaFX and Java licence now.

The post [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/206697) says that we don't have to release our source code that uses JavaFX due to the GPL + Classpath exception. The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703496/4594511) says:

> As of February 2013, JavaFX is partially open source and should become almost fully open source over the next few months.

The [post here](http://fxexperience.com/2013/02/february-open-source-update/) lists many of JavaFX's projects that have been open sourced, including "javafx-common".

Am I allowed to use JavaFX freely in my commercial applications or not? Do all of my above posts relate to OpenJFX not JavaFX? I have developed using JavaFX, not OpenJFX. Is this a massive mistake? If so, how easy is it to transition from JavaFX code to OpenJFX?

I'm so confused and just want a simple answer.

Comment: I'm not seeking legal advice, and agree to not hold any user accountable for any information that they share. I'm only seeking personal opinions which could help clarify my obvious confusion. Literally anything you say that doesn't suggest I consult a lawyer is extremely valuable to me.

Comment: You should ask the owner. If they do not explicitly say on their website, they likely have contact information.

Comment: Ask the owner... who is that? Oracle? If you can find me a contact email address I'd certainly contact them. I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 4):

Since it is an Oracle product, the definitive answer for JavaFX should be found on [Oracle's website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#10):

> JavaFX is available under the same [license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html) and business model as Java SE. This includes the ability for third party developers to distribute the runtime libraries with their application(s), subject to the terms and conditions of the license.

The relevant part of "the license" appears to be:

> Oracle grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable, limited license without fees to reproduce and distribute those files specifically identified as redistributable in the README File ("Redistributables") provided that: (i) you distribute the Redistributables complete and unmodified, and only bundled as part of Programs, (ii) the Programs add significant and primary functionality to the Redistributables, (iii) you do not distribute additional software intended to supersede any component(s) of the Redistributables (unless otherwise specified in the applicable README File), (iv) you do not remove or alter any proprietary legends or notices contained in or on the Redistributables, (v) you only distribute the Redistributables pursuant to a license agreement that: (a) is a complete, unmodified reproduction of this Agreement; or (b) protects Oracle's interests consistent with the terms contained in the Agreement and includes the notice set forth in Section H, (vi) you agree to defend and indemnify Oracle and its licensors from and against any damages, costs, liabilities, settlement amounts and/or expenses (including attorneys' fees) incurred in connection with any claim, lawsuit or action by any third party that arises or results from the use or distribution of any and all Programs and/or Software.

However, if you are in any doubt, you should of course consult Oracle and/or a lawyer as appropriate.

Comment: thanks for your time. I've read this previously and interpreted as follows, perhaps you could comment on whether you agree/disagree with any point? `Oracle grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable, limited license without fees` means it's free to use JavaFX in a commercial application, so long as: `you distribute the Redistributables complete and unmodified, and only bundled as part of Programs` ... means I can't modify the JavaFx source code, but that I CAN bundle it with my commercial app. I have no idea what this means:

Comment: `the Programs add significant and primary functionality to the Redistributables`. Does that mean my program must somehow advance the JavaFX source code, instead of merely USING the code? That doesn't seem right. `do not distribute additional software intended to supersede any component(s) of the Redistributables` means don't alter the source code nor create software that makes the Redistributables` obsolete. The remaining points all require that I don't modify their license, but ensure it's present in my distributables, and also don't sue them. Is that all correct? Free commercial use seems OK

Comment: @Mathomatic The part you quoted just says that you must bundle the Redistributable with your program (don't offer it as a separate download). The part about "significant functionality" is probably so you don't just include the Redistributable along with a dummy program as a way of skirting that requirement.

Comment: @Brandin, so it means my program must be legitimate in it's application/requirement of the Redistributables, got it. But,  #4 FAQ found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#4) says `[JavaFX] code is available under the GPL v2 with Classpath Exception license, similar to other projects in OpenJDK. The Oracle JavaFX runtime and SDK implementations will continue to be released under the Oracle Binary Code License for the Java SE Platform.`. The runtime is crucial though, yet it's not under GPL + Classpath? That's why I'm confused about bundling it

Comment: Then lower down it says `JavaFX is available under the same license and business model as Java SE. This includes the ability for third party developers to distribute the runtime librairies with their application(s), subject to the terms and conditions of the license.` .... so I *can* bundle the JavaFX runtime, freely, along with my commercial application which uses the JavaFX codebase? I'm confused why it says runtime = BCL and then it says I can freely distribute (bundle?) it. Thoughts?

Comment: @Mathomatic I think you should treat 'JavaFX' and 'OpenJFX' as two separate projects. OpenJFX has an open source license (GPL); the source code contributed to that one is open source as required by the GPL. JavaFX released by Oracle uses the Oracle Binary Code License. You can redistribute the runtime because the license permits you to do so (you just quoted parts of it above).

Comment: `I am effectively saying that you cannot use JavaFX in a commercial application unless you acquire a commercial license from Oracle as in the vast majority of cases the Oracle BCL does not license JavaFX for a commercial usage (and that to the best of my knowledge there is no free, libre or open source JavFX runtime available anywhere).` Would you agree that he seems to be mistaken, given the information we've covered above? Simply asking for your opinion here, thank you!

Comment: @Mathomatic The only place the license says something like that is in section "A. COMMERCIAL FEATURES." but if you read it carefully it tells you how to comply with the license, even when you're using those features.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51461/discussion-between-brandin-and-mathomatic).

Comment: @Brandin, what is your personal opinion about [this post](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/how-to-comply-to-lgpl-with-maven-jar-packages/4586?noredirect=1#comment12826_4586) by Phillipe which says: `there are practically no commercial usage possible of code that uses the Oracle BCL including the JavaFX runtime unless you buy a commercial license. The use cases are very narrow and unless you get a strong legal advice you expose yourself to audits from Oracle. Unless there is effectively an open source runtime for JavaFX in which case you would have to build this yourself.`

Comment: This seems to contradict our chat yesterday, wherein we seemed to agree that the BCL *does* allow for distribution of the runtime, and is actually a less risky license than OpenJFX's (and associated runtime). The JavaFX FAQ clearly say `JavaFX is available under the same license and business model as Java SE. This includes the ability for third party developers to distribute the runtime librairies with their application(s), subject to the terms and conditions of the license.` I'm so confused!! In your opinion can I distribute the JavaFX (BCL) runtime freely with my commercial app? I thought so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51550/discussion-between-brandin-and-mathomatic).

Answer (score 3):

See my answer to [this closely related question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/4586/947). The gist is:

- You cannot use the BCL-licensed JavaFX as provided by Oracle as pre-built for much anything beyond some evaluation and development
- You can use the GPL+Classpath exception-licensed JavaFX runtime and open source libraries with an OpenJDK runtime for pretty much anything including commercial applications. You need to either build it yourself from sources or find a pre-built one (and this is NOT provided by Oracle)

Comment: Thanks Phillipe, I'm in the process of transitioning to OpenJDK now. Quick question: I've been developing using Oracle's JDK/JavaSE/JavaFX for sometime now, but only for personal use on my personal laptop. I haven't shared my code with anybody. Am I still at risk of an audit in your opinion? I can't imagine, since millions of people use Java for free everyday. Thoughts?

Comment: You are not at risk for personal or development usage

Comment: And practically the Oracle BCL does not give any audit rights to Oracle. Only a commercial contract would be able to do this (and Oracle is primarily going after its own commercial customers preferably the ones with deeper pockets first...).